# Selecting images for correct iPhone size - 3.5/4/4.7/5.5

Tags: ios

I am following these `#define` functions for adjusting the sizes of height instead of using Asset Catalogs. If i use Asset Catalogs for 6 and 6 Plus, the height has a problem. Is there any other way to adjust the image for screen height easily?

```
 #define IS_IPHONE5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - (         double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

#define IS_IPHONE6 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )667 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - (    double )736 )< DBL_EPSILON )

   // using if statements in the methods 

 if (IS_iphone5) {
    bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage5.png"];}
else if(IS_IPHONE6){
     bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage6.png"];}
else if(IS_IPHONE6PLUS){
     bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupagep.png"];}
 else {
     bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage.png"];}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, I think, whether this is really necessary. What's the actual problem? Do you just want to choose the right image for the right device? Then why not just use an asset catalog, which chooses it for you? It seems to me you might be making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Like matt said, use asset catalog, makes having device specific images easy pz

Comment: when i use asset catalog for 3.5 and 6plus height edges are cutting itself but when i follow this code its coming in right way

Comment: @anjani Then you made your images the wrong size, or you're placing them incorrectly.

Comment: i fixed for 3.5 and 4 inch but still cant figure out  for  6 and 6plus

Answer (score 0):

i just fixed my problem after working out as i mentioned in the question #define function , so that we can adjust the  buttons and nodes  throughout the app with if statements.

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - (         double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

#define IS_IPHONE6 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )667 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - (    double )736 )< DBL_EPSILON )

// just adjust the height and width with - or +  
//if there is image adjust with scale mode
    bg.xScale = 0.5;// adjust these according your requirement 
    bg.yScale = 0.5;

   bg.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2-30, self.size.height/2+280)
  if (IS_iphone5) {
bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage5.png"];

}
 else if(IS_IPHONE6){
 bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage6.png"];}
 else if(IS_IPHONE6PLUS){
 bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupagep.png"];}
  else {
 bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"menupage.png"];}
```